# How can I use equivalent of SELECT * with WHERE in SqlAlchemy statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

Trying to extract data from Redshift table using SQLAlchemy but finding the documentation difficult to follow for my use case.

Code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.sql import  select
from getpass import getpass
import psycopg2
import missingno as msno
import dask.dataframe as dd 

#PASSWORD INPUT PROMPT
pwd = getpass('password')
username = 'my.user'
password = pwd
server = 'some_host.redshift.amazonaws.com'
database = 'some_database'
port = '1234'

connection_string = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{server}:{port}/{database}'

engine = create_engine(connection_string)

metadata = MetaData()

t = Table('table_name', metadata,
    Column('column_name', primary_key=True),
   schema='my_schema')


df = dd.read_sql_table(t, connection_string, index_col='column_name', npartitions=50, columns=None)
```

**My questions**

1. How do I perform the equivalent of `SELECT * WHERE foo_bar = 'foo'`
2. Do I really have to state of all the column names in `'t = '`

Comment: If you're using `engine`, you can do something like `with engine.connect() as connection: ...` and execute the raw SQL statement within this context as `connection.execute("{SQL statement}")`. I'm hesitant to link you to the docs since you said you've already seen it, but [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html) is the link nonetheless.

Comment: Have you tried `df = dd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE foo_bar = 'foo'", ...)` ?